# SQL CREATE and SELECT processing simulation in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, data-structures, sql-processor

I want to simulate simple SQL statement (Create & Select) processing in Java.

For example, consider following two relations

```
CREATE TABLE X( a, b, c);
CREATE TABLE Y( c, d, e);
```

**Ques 1:** 
Now what data structures can I use to store the relation name X and Y along with their attributes .

Also consider the select statement:

```
SELECT a,d FROM X,Y WHERE X.c = Y.c ;
```

**Ques 2:** 
How to confirm whether **a belongs to X or Y** and **d belongs to X or Y** ?
How does this processing is taken care inside SQL query processing engine.

I can find numerous query evaluation plans that pushes the SELECT statement below JOIN operation if the Selection depends on only on a single relation. For this purpose I need to know **How to confirm to which relation the attribute belongs to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ques 1: Now what data structures can I use to store the relation name X and Y along with their attributes .

Use any structure you like, in Java you'd most probably use classes that correspond to X and Y and which have fields that correspond to a, b, c for X and c, d, e for Y.

> SELECT a,d FROM X,Y WHERE X.c = Y.c ;
>
> Ques 2: How to confirm whether a belongs to X or Y and d belongs to X or Y ? How does this processing is taken care inside SQL query processing engine.

Since `a` only exists in X and `d` only exists in Y the database knows what's meant. If they'd exist in the other table as well you'd need to specify which of them you mean (e.g. `SELECT x.a, d FROM X x, Y y ...`).